# Android NavigationDrawer without Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a Navigation Drawer in my app, without the ActionBar. My previous attempt using NoActionBar themes in the styles works but now I can't swipe to open the navigation menu. 
I need something like this:

[image]

How can I go about this?

Comment: what you can do is design your own created button and use it to open a drawer.

Comment: @orvenito Yeah,that's a great idea,will try it out

Comment: Create a drawable which look like the navigation icon and use noactionbar theme, then if u r using activity or fragment use transparent toolbar with single imageview inside toolbar

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the `toolbar` from the app_bar_home.xml.
Add an ImageView, set it to that position and set an `onClickListener` to it.
Use this code for ImageView.

```
    final ImageView toolbar1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Toolbar1); 
    final DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toolbar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
         }
     });
```

Change your theme related to this.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

This works great as I'm using it.

Comment: how can you add and call DrawerLayout??

Answer (score 0):

I have done this same type of Navigation drawer in my previous project

Just apply some changes in **style.xml** and **layout.xml** file

### **style.xml**

```
     <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

> **Note:** Put **AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent** named theme on both file style.xml and style.xml(v21)

### **Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user22.nevigationdrawer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

- Make changes on **app_bar_yourlayout_name.xml**

### **app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.user22.nevigationdrawer.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_hotel_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBar_hotel_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

**if You want to change the NavigationDrawer ActionBar icon than just change in your NavigationDrawer main java file**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

**toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener**

```
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
```

> Note: Remove onBackPressed() method from your java file if you change icon of Navigation Drawer

[image]